# How to attribute the HashMap values of returned JSON to TextViews in RecyclerView rows

Tags: android, hashmap

As a result from an API call, I receive a Hashmap `<String,Integer>`. Within the `onResponse` method, I can output it in the console as follows:

```
 public void onResponse(Call<UsersStackOverflow> call, Response<UsersStackOverflow> response) {

            int code = response.code();
            List<User> users = response.body().getUsers();

            myDataSource.clear();
            myDataSource.addAll(response.body().getUsers());
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            for (User user: users) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Name: " + user.getUserName() +
                                "; Location: " + user.getLocation() +
                                "; Reputation:  " + user.getReputation()
                );

                System.out.println("Badges: ");

                for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : user.getBadges().entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey().toString();
                    Integer value = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
                }
            }
```

Each of thee pieces of data I'd want to show in different rows via a `RecyclerView`. Within the `onBindViewHolder()` of the adapter, I show the data this way:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.userLocation.setText("Location: "+users.get(position).getLocation());
    holder.userReputation.setText("Reputation: " + users.get(position).getReputation());
    holder.userName.setText("Username: " + users.get(position).getUserName());
    holder.goldenBdge.setText(
            (users.get(position).getBadges().keySet().toString()));

}
```

But how should I extract the key-value pairs from the HashMap? Thank you!

Comment: Do you intend to show each of this location, reputation, name and badges data in different row of recylcerview?

Comment: Yes, Textviews for each of them. Succeeded in receiving the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users.get(position).getBadges().entrySet()
```

that returns a Set containing all of the mappings in this Map. Each mapping is an instance of *Map.Entry*. As the Set is backed by this Map, changes in one will be reflected in the other.

i think this is how you Iterate through the  pairs:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> it  = hash.entrySet().iterator();
        do{
            Map.Entry<Integer,String> pair = it.next();
            pair.getKey();
            pair.getValue();
        }while(it.hasNext());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked great! I attributed the values received to TextViews and the result is as I wanted.

Comment: Raafat,may you tell me,  how do I access all of the key-value pairs? I couldn't find it.movenext() or something like that. Thanks!